# REGEX letras, números y espacios

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando validar con Regex que el valor obtenido sea una combinación de números, letras o espacios en blanco. No puntos, no comas, no signos.
Esta es la prueba

```js
var str = "la mejor forma de jugar 123!!";
var patt = new RegExp(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g);
var res = patt.test(str);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

Me regresa TRUE, me debería regresar FALSE, pues hay signos de puntuación.
Que esta fallando

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En realidad hay dos problemas en la expresión regular:

Por una parte te devuelve `true` porque lo que hace es buscar alguna cadena que coincida con el patrón dentro de la cadena a testear. Con que una parte de la cadena coincida con el patrón es suficiente. Para indicar que es la cadena completa la que debe coincidir con el patrón definido en la expresión regular deberías añadir un carácter `^` al comienzo de la expresión (que indica que la coincidencia debe comenzar al principio de la cadena) y un carácter `$` al final (que indica que la coincidencia debe acabar al final de la cadena).

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g
```

Por otro lado en el conjunto de caracteres no estás contemplando el espacio, por lo que este carácter también haría que devolviera un resultado de no coincidencia. Deberías añadir el espacio al conjunto de caracteres

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g
```

```js
var str = "la mejor forma de jugar 123!!";
var patt = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g);
var res = patt.test(str);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: Buena explicación, gracias.